# Question about the norm of a bounded linear operator and its product with its adjoint.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $T: U \to V$ be a bounded linear operator between two real Hilbert spaces $U, V$. Then, is it true that $$\|Tu\| = \|(T^*T)^{1/2}u\| \ \text{for any} \ u \in U$$ where $T^*$ denotes the adjoint of $T$.

Now, my part is $$\|Tu\|^2 = \langle Tu, Tu\rangle = \langle T^*Tu, u\rangle  = \langle (T^*T)^{1/2}u,  (T^*T)^{1/2} u\rangle $$  $$= \| (T^*T)^{1/2}u\|^2  $$

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your proof is correct. You should mention that $T^*T$ and $(T^*T)^{1/2}$ are self-adjoint.